# Transform object to a more complex nested object javascript

Tags: javascript

If I have the following data:

```js
const data = [
  {
    label: 'Q1',
    seriesname: 'Food products',
    value: '1000'
  },
  {
    label: 'Q1',
    seriesname: 'Non-Food products',
    value: '2000'
  },
  {
    label: 'Q2',
    seriesname: 'Food products',
    value: '3400'
  },
  {
    label: 'Q2',
    seriesname: 'Non-Food products',
    value: '2200'
  },
];

console.log(data);
```

I need to find a way to transform these data into this format:

```js
const dataTransformed = [
  {
    seriesname: 'Food Products',
    data: [
      // Q1 
      {
        value: '1000',
      },
      // Q2
      {
        value: '3400',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    seriesname: 'Non-Food Products',
    data: [
      // Q1 
      {
        value: '2000',
      },
      // Q2
      {
        value: '2200',
      },
    ],
  },
];

console.log(dataTransformed);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to filter that initial array and do your manipulations on it. Did you at least try something so we could help?

Comment: You have given no indication of how `data` may vary.